# log4net possible missing configuration

Tags: c#, xml, unity-game-engine, package, log4net

I created another class to be used as middle class of ILog interface (which implements all ILog interface). I know about LogManager but I need custom class (as part of a solution of reflecting...)

So the situation is that I want to call each function in that class with the type of the class that called the custom ILog class.

I succeeded and now, bottom line is that every time I use the function it's printed with row zero. Custom Class:

```
LoggerManager{

   public void Print(object message){Log.Debug(..)}
   //calls Log.Debug with the type ILog of UsingClass
```

Usage:

```
UsingClass.Print("Hello");
```

Outcome:

```
type_of_usingClass Hello:0
```

I want to change to show the line of which the function was called inside UsingClass.
It showing up in the stack-trace with the corrent line but not right on the line without stack-trace.

Thanks a lot!